# Rails methods - Implementing range search - Need Advise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am implementing a range search in my code to retrieve values from my database: So lets say for example I have a database of listings of bus-stops in a certain city. I have a mobile device that sends latitude and longitude values to Rails via JSON and I want rails to retrieve all the bus-stops within a 1 km radius of that point.

So far I have a Listing Model that looks like this:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base


  #This method shows listings around a point
  def self.find_around(_latitude, _longitude)

    self.where('latittude = _latitude','longitude = _longitude')

  end
end
```

I have a listing_controller that looks like this

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController

  def around(_latitude,_longitude) 

    @listings_around = Listing.find_around(_latitude, _longitude)

  end


  def index   
    #self.create_listings
    @listings = Listing.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #index.html.erb
    end
end
```

So I know there is something wrong with the syntax of these methods. Im new to Rails, and I come from a Java background. Im trying to understand the whole concept of REST and resources, while Im write this method.
Im trying to learn these things:

1) How to structure the method syntax so that the client will be able to invoke the method and pass the 2 paramters:latitude and longitude to rails.

2) The next thing I want to try is to write the actual algorithm in Ruby where given these coordinates, I would like to find everything within a 1 km radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part, try the [geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)

It provides location aware database queries, and you could lookup some venues near a coordinate like this: `Venue.near([40.71, 100.23], 20)` (for example, this says look for venues in 20 miles around this coordinate)